# Geometric Series in Polar Form

Tags: complex-numbers, geometric-series

I'm stuck on a complex number problem relating to the geometric series in polar form. By considering that:
$$1+\operatorname{cis}{\theta}+\operatorname{cis}{2\theta}+\operatorname{cis}{3\theta}+....+\operatorname{cis}{n\theta}$$
as a geometric series, find:
$$\sum_{r=0}^n \operatorname{cos}{r\theta}$$
I was thinking along the lines of finding the sum of the polar form series, and that I was assuming that the sum of the series would be:
$$\operatorname{cis}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{\theta}$$
Thus, if that is the answer then finding the sum of $\operatorname{cos}{r\theta}$ becomes very easy. But I doubt that that is the answer, so any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: if $z \ne 1$ : $\sum_{r=0}^n z^r = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$.

Comment: I'm confused? How does the left hand side equate to the right hand side?